# Splitting line at point positions using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, line, splitting

I have a polyline and I have two points on the polyline.

I would like to know if there is a tool or script that I could use to split my original polyline into 3 polylines? (Starting point to point A, Point A to B and B to ending point of the polyline)?

I am looking for an automatic process rather splitting the  line manually.

Comment: how do you decide where B is? You might want to google LRS GRASS (linear referencing system) and see if that is the same concept.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS won't do this natively to the best of my knowledge. However, you can use GRASS from within QGIS, and [this thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/How-to-split-a-line-using-points-td4981464.html) looks like exactly what you want. I haven't tested this, but it all makes sense. Credit of course goes to the folks in that thread. First, you would import your data into GRASS then:

> dump the coordinates to a text file (v.out.ascii) then loop thru that file, and
>   feed the coords to v.edit, like so:
>   v.out.ascii  out=points.txt while read x y; do
>   v.edit  tool=break coord=$x,$y cat=0-99999 done < points.txt

Note the caveat that your points must be exactly on the line.

Or, even simpler in a bash environment:

> v.out.ascii format=point in=pts --q | cut -d'|' -f1,2 | tr '|' ',' |
>   while read COOR; do v.edit map=line tool=break coords=$COOR; done

Comment: Can you simplified it. I am first timer ON grass.

Answer (score 1):

If qgis cannot do that, shapely  (a python module for manipulating shapefiles) seems able to do what you want.

Check [http://sgillies.net/blog/1040/shapely-recipes/](https://web.archive.org/web/20100710162902/https://sgillies.net/blog/1040/shapely-recipes/)

To install the module, from you command terminal type: `$ sudo pip install shapely`

Comment: Clarification: Shapely is an interface to GEOS and does computational geometry. It doesn't know anything about shapefiles.

Comment: link doesnt work anymore

Answer (score 0):

I just used GRASS module v.net.connect to carry out this task. Pay attention to distances points are away from lines (required input). Import lines and points to GRASS, find the v.net module, select the 'connect' option and set necessary parameters.
I'm an amateur with GRASS and managed to get it done - getting GRASS and QGIS to work was the biggest hurdle!