# Split Lines with Points Layer Tool

Tags: qgis

I asked a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85226/splitting-a-lines-layer-using-points/85287?noredirect=1#85287) a while ago to figure out how to split a line layer with a points layer using QGIS, but cannot, however, get the accepted answer to work due to limitations of my knowledge and the fact that i'm working on Windows 7. I noticed this feature [request](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5040) that dates from about a year ago, requesting a tool that accomplishes exactly what I need. I've been looking for it, don't see it, and am wondering if it is currently an available tool and i'm just not looking in the right spot or not.

Comment: Splitting lines with points can get a bit tricky if your points don't lie exactly on your line, as viewed by whatever process your particular computational device, software, and its operating system chooses to make that decision.  You may prefer for simple tasks buffering your points (something a purist should avoid, but a producer should embrace).  You may also wish to use ST_ClosestPoint, for points that lie within that buffer, a good compromise.  For best results you should try to understand where the points should be on the line without needing the point layer at all (if possible).

Comment: I've got an algorithm I use for a similar procedure (splitting lines based on relative point positions), but I've written it in T-SQL.  Hopefully you can wait a bit for me to translate it.

Comment: i had considered buffering points, but felt concerned about the tiny space that would remain between lines. I wonder if v.clean would be capable of correcting this in a second treatment. I would appreciate taking a look at your algorithm once translated as well.

Answer (score 5):

The Networks plugin has a function called "Connect":

This tool allows you to connect node layer objects to a linear objects layer. Each point will be connected to the nearest polyline, if the shortest distance to the polyline is lower than the search radius, the polyline will be split in two parts from each side of the connection point, in order to preserve the network topology.
NB : Multilinestrings are ignored

Comment: Unfortunately, at 3.6.2, using the Networks > Network > Connect Nodes to Line tool causes QGIS to crash.

Comment: I am having the same issue of QGIS crash in QGIS 3.6.3