# Does QgsSpatialIndex() support Z values, respectively 3D distances?

Tags: pyqgis, 3d, spatial-index

I am wondering if [`QgsSpatialIndex()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsSpatialIndex.html) does support Z values, respectively 3D distances?

*If too short to read:*

Looking at the underlying [libspatialindex](https://libspatialindex.org/en/latest/) I cannot find information neither. However, [rtree](https://rtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#d-indexes) does support 3D:

> As of Rtree version 0.5.0, you can create 3D (actually kD) indexes.
> The following is a 3D index that is to be stored on disk. Persisted
> indexes are stored on disk using two files – an index file (.idx) and
> a data (.dat) file. You can modify the extensions these files use by
> altering the properties of the index at instantiation time. The
> following creates a 3D index that is stored on disk as the files
> 3d_index.data and 3d_index.index

Back to `QgsSpatialIndex()`, which

> Creates an empty R-tree index.

let's take `.nearestNeighbor()` for example to find nearest 3D points:

The docs state it requires a `QgsPointXY()` as input:

> nearestNeighbor(self, point: QgsPointXY, neighbors: int = 1,
> maxDistance: float = 0)

which makes me think it does not support 3D distances. However, you can also hand over a `QgsGeometry()` instead:

> nearestNeighbor(self, geometry: QgsGeometry, neighbors: int = 1,
> maxDistance: float = 0) -> List[int] Returns nearest neighbors to a
> geometry. The number of neighbors returned is specified by the
> neighbors argument.

`QgsGeometry()` does support Z values. However, for `QgsGeometry()` there is (as far as I know) no method to measure 3D distances. For example `QgsGeometry().distance()` says:

> QgsGeometry objects are inherently Cartesian/planar geometries, and
> the distance returned by this method is calculated using strictly
> Cartesian mathematics.

So for example

```
geom1 = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('Point(1 1 0')
geom2 = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('Point(1 1 5')
print(geom1.distance(geom2))
```

returns 0.0.

Additionally, you cannot use a `QgsPoint()`.

There is no more information about it. So taking a look at [`QgsSpatialIndexKDBush()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsSpatialIndexKDBush.html#module-QgsSpatialIndexKDBush) it says:

> A very fast static spatial index for 2D points based on a flat
> KD-tree.

Which makes me think "why is 2D mentioned here? Is it because only the KDBush index does not support 3D?"

Is there any documentation about 3D support or a way to figure out if and how `QgsSpatialIndex()` measures (3D) distances? *Or an alternative index supporting 3D measures?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any documation on this, but according to my tests, **no, `QgsSpatialIndex()` does not support 3D measures**. Try:

```py
vl = QgsVectorLayer("PointZ", "temp", "memory") # adding and saving to a layer, otherwise feature ids are all the same
pr = vl.dataProvider()

vl.startEditing()

f1 = QgsFeature()
geom1 = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('Point(1 1 0')
f1.setGeometry(geom1)
pr.addFeature(f1)

f2 = QgsFeature()
geom2 = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('Point(1 1 10')
f2.setGeometry(geom2)
pr.addFeature(f2)

f3 = QgsFeature()
geom3 = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('Point(1 1 500')
f3.setGeometry(geom3)
pr.addFeature(f3)

f4 = QgsFeature()
geom4 = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('Point(1 2 0')
f4.setGeometry(geom4)
pr.addFeature(f4)

vl.commitChanges()
vl.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

idx = QgsSpatialIndex(flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries)
#idx = QgsSpatialIndex() # there is no difference with or without stored geometries
idx.addFeature(f1)
idx.addFeature(f2)
idx.addFeature(f3)
idx.addFeature(f4)

nn = idx.nearestNeighbor(geom1,-1)
print(nn)
for fid in nn:
    print('Feat ' + str(fid) + ' WKT: ' + idx.geometry(fid).asWkt())
```

returns:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4]
Feat 1 WKT: PointZ (1 1 0)
Feat 3 WKT: PointZ (1 1 500)
Feat 2 WKT: PointZ (1 1 10)
Feat 4 WKT: PointZ (1 2 0)
```

while it actually should return:

```
[1, 4, 2, 3]
Feat 1 WKT: PointZ (1 1 0)
Feat 4 WKT: PointZ (1 2 0)
Feat 2 WKT: PointZ (1 1 10)
Feat 3 WKT: PointZ (1 1 500)
```

*Please correct me if my tests are invalid, incorrect, I am missing something or some docs state something different.*

Comment: Same goes for `overlay_nearest()` function; you can test with `array_to_string(overlay_nearest(@layer,geom_to_wkt($geometry),limit:=-1))`