# Split a line feature using nearby points

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a line shapefile and a point shapefile, and

- the line has its own segments

[image]

and its attribute table,

[image]

- the point shapefile has points near the line above, not on it

[image]

and the close look,

[image]

**Can I use QGIS or other open source tools to split this line at locations which are nearest to the points？** **And after this procedure I can get the original line with more segments(because being split).** For example, find the location on the line, which is the nearest to the point, and split the line at this location(star).

[image]

I am using QGIS 2.2 under Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: Could you add a diagram of what you are trying to do, showing the line (and its nodes), the points, and the resulting split lines (with new node)? What do you mean by the 'line ... has already been split'?

Comment: @Simbamangu I have edited my post.

Comment: In the final image, why is the yellow star the desired point? Why not just to the direct left of the point?

Comment: You could use the SAGA Split lines at Points tool with high epsilon (tolerance value).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this could be done in QGIS but you could use [st_split](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html) for this if it helps. Try to make a buffer around your points and then split it where they intersect.

A same question is asked at [Splitting line at point positions using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30447/how-to-split-a-line-at-point-positions)

Answer (score -2):

Now [**Closest Point** plugin version 4.0.1](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ClosestPoint/) for QGIS 3 can do such cutting task.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.