# QGIS: Creating a point at a set distance up/downstream from another point (dams or obstructions) on a line object (river)

Tags: qgis, line, buffer, hydrology, upstream

I have a data set where I have shapefiles for the watercourses in a drainage basin (line/linestring) and locations of dams and other obstructions along them (points). I would like to create a new linestring layer which follows the water course approximately 100m upstream from each point representing a dam. The result of this analysis would be a new layer composed of several lines measuring 100m upstream from a dam/obstruction, but I would also be open to creating new features as opposed to new objects.

Comment: Does this help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/410820/88814

Comment: Hi, I think this could be very useful, thank you for the comment!