# Selecting a line between 2 points

Tags: qgis

I am trying to provide a data layer in QGIS 3.24 to show areas where further survey is required along an existing line.  I have data with a start and end point in a .csv as below.

[image]

I want to use this data to select these 2 points on this predefined line and highlight the line in between the 2 points and not all the other lines either side.  I don’t won’t a straight line between the 2 points but to follow the existing geometry. Each length between3.24 the start and end point will be a different distance.

[image]

Any ideas on the best way to do this when you have a large amount of data?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Is your question how to split a line with points? If so, see here how to do it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392633/88814