# Splitting linestring only when another linestrings endpoint intersects using QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, expression, splitting, linestring

Using QGIS, is it possible to split all the linestrings in a file only if another linestring's endpoint intersected the linestring but not if they completely cross each other?

For example, the image below shows when the line segments would be split.

[image]

While this image shows when they would not be split.

[image]

Comment: A combination of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306190/generating-start-and-end-points-for-linestrings and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30447/splitting-line-at-point-positions-using-qgis ?

Comment: Dear @user8675309, be aware that if you use `python`-tag, means at one moment you have to provide a snippet of your code that you currently possess, otherwise your question may be closed as not explicit enough. Maybe try firstly focus on a solution without codding.

Comment: @Taras: Great that for expression-questions you don't have to provide code-snippets... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the end-points and the lines and create a small line that passed through this point - the small red lines in the screenshot below. Use this expression with [Geomtry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=geometry%20expression#geometry-by-expression) (you might change the length of the line - `10000` in my case):

   ```
   extend (
       make_line (
           end_point ($geometry), 
           project (
               end_point ($geometry),
               10000,
               radians (
                   angle_at_vertex( 
                       $geometry, -1
       )))),
       10000,
       0
       )
   ```
2. Use [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html?highlight=split%20lines#split-with-lines)

*Screenshot: original lines in black, behind it the blue line is the result with the yellow highlighted part selected. End-points (red) and lines used to split (red) were created with geometry generator for visualization with the expression from above:*

[image]